# feynmp-auto and MacTex 2017

Tags: feynmp-auto

After updating to MacTex 2017, I found feynmp-auto does not work anymore? It produces a empty page without any compiler error. Does anyone find similar problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately, `mpost` has been withdrawn from the list of “safe” programs. You need to activate shell-escape.