# Use Feynmp to create feynman diagram in LaTeXiT

Tags: feynman, feynmf, latexit, feynmp

I want to create a Feynman diagram using LaTeXiT.
I have followed the instructions here [http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp.html](http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Etaku/osx/feynmp.html) to install feynmp and the instructions here [http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html](http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Etaku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html) to set up LaTeXiT to produce Feynman diagrams but when I run the preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths%\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp}
```

and the code:

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(110,60)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

I get a blank picture as the output. No error, just no picture.
I'm working on MacOS Catalina with LaTeXiT Version 2.13.2. Can someone tell me the best way to get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I couldn't get it to work either, even with TeXShop. I hope someone will have the solution.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL thanks for trying at least!

Comment: @BethLong I teach physics so I have an interest in getting it to work.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397694/218142

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL definitely relevant, but also pretty unhelpful at least for an in-expert like me!

Comment: Try putting the line `% !TEX program = sepdflatex` at the top of your file and typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-Tj.

Comment: @HerbSchulz That didn't work for me. The log says the file  `feyngraph.1` doesn't exist. Looks like it's not being created.

Comment: @HerbSchulz It doesn't appear in my working directory with the other aux files.

Comment: Sorry, ti isn't created because, for some reason, mpost isn't being run on the fyngraph.mp file. This is even with --shell-escape enabled (which is what sepdflatex does).

Comment: @HerbSchulz Confirmed! I manually ran mpost on the .mp file and got the .1 file, but now the log shows "Unknown graphics extension: .1" message.

Comment: @HerbSchulz That worked! Thank you!

Comment: It finally worked for me. I had to manually run mpost on the .mp file, delete the existing PDF, and reprocess from inside TeXShop.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Any ideas on fixing this? Beth, I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying Herb Schulz's answer above, I find the following works in LaTeXiT:
Preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
% !TEX program = pdflatexmk
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
```

Figure:

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(110,60)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used particular setup but fenymp package doesn't try to run mpost for you, your build system should be doing this as part of the process and will need to detect that an .mp has been created or updated and it should therefore run that step as well.

The other option if you do want the main build to run mpost is to use the feynmp-auto package which should then run mpost for you (at which point --shell-escape becomes relevant as mentioned in comments on the question). Your build system will still need to notice that some of the input has changed and re-run the build or you will need to re-run the build.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the information from the answer above

```
% !TEX program = pdflatexmk
% !TEX parameter = -shell-escape 
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths%\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(110,60)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

will work fine in TeXShop. The pdflatexmk engine used will automatically make the second run of pdflatex and note the use of feynmp-auto package to do the mpost run.

Comment: I can confirm this works. Any idea why the `sepdflatexmk` engine wasn't doing this before? Obviously the `!TEX parameter = -shell-escape` is necessary, but I thought that's what the `se` stood for.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL: the engine was sepdflatex which just runs pdflatex with --shell-escape enabled as apposed to sepdflatexmk which is a latexmk based engine. The two lines `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` and `% !TEX parameter = -shell-escape` are equivalent to using sepdflatexmk. Note also that `feymp-auto` is used instead of `feynmp`.

Comment: I tried using `feymp-auto` yesterday and I still had to manually run Metapost. Must be something specific to my setup.

Comment: When you run the pdflatexmk engine does the Console show that --shell-escape is added to the pdflatex command line? What version of TeXShop are you using? If you've been using TeXShop for a long time you may have to update the latexmk engines. Just move the updated versions from `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Latexmk` up two levels to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` replacing the versions already there? The updated engnes understand that `% !TEX parameter = -shell-escape` line.

Comment: It does now (and I'm using the latest TeXShop). I moved the `sepdflatex` engine from the Inactive folder last night, but for some reason it still didn't work unless I manually ran Metapost AND deleted the blank PDF file. Now it even works without the `% !TEX parameter = -shell-escape` line. I'm thoroughly confused but it does work now.

Answer (score 1):

None of the proposed solutions with `feynmp-auto` here worked for me in LaTeXiT 2.14.5.
It turned out something got scrambled when updating TeX Live on macOS Mojave (10.14.6). I had to install a separate version of GhostScript, see e.g. [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313920/latexit-does-not-render-anymore).
After that I followed the [usual instructions by Taku Yamanaka](http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Etaku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html), and updated the paths for `dvipdf`, `gs` and `ps2pdf` under Preferences > Typesetting > Behavior, which were all three available from `/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.54.0/bin/`.