# Cannot get Feynmp to work in LaTeXiT

Tags: latexit, feynmp, feynmp-auto

In trying to use feynmp to draw Feynman diagrams in LaTeXiT, I followed the instructions at [http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html](http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Etaku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html) and found it runs with no errors but does not produce any drawing. This problem has been encountered and discussed previously, see [Use Feynmp to create feynman diagram in LaTeXiT](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567056/use-feynmp-to-create-feynman-diagram-in-latexit), and the suggestion was to run preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
% !TEX program = pdflatexmk
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
```

and the code

```
  \begin{fmfgraph}(110,60)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

but I find that does not work for me. I have tried adding -shell-escape to the commands listed under Preferences > Typesetting, to no avail. I also do not know if I have to change some other settings to implement "% !TEX program = pdflatexmk". Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I don’t believe LaTeXiT understands that directive; it belongs to TeXShop. Does using the standalone package and typesetting in TeXShop work?

Comment: Yes, feynmp works well in TeXShop. However I need to get a transparent background for the drawings that feynmp produces, to be used in a Keynote presentation, and that's why I'm trying to use LaTeXiT.